# print in a row but a little different. python

Tags: python

my code

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
for i in range(4):
       print 0.5,a[i],
```

output

```
0.5 1 0.5 2 0.5 3 0.5 4
```

but I want to output

```
0.5 1 2 3 4
```

How to solve this problem?

thanks in advance!

Comment: print 0.5 before entering the loop

Answer (score 3):

No need to use `range`

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
print 0.5,
for i in a:
       print i,
```

Answer (score 2):

Just `print` the `0.5` before your loop.

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
print 0.5,
for i in a:
       print i,
```

Answer (score 0):

For the list itself, you can do:

```
>>> ' '.join(map(str, a))
'1 2 3 4'
```

To print multiple types of objects, most use [str.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings):

```
>>> print '{} {}'.format(.5, ' '.join(map(str,a)))
0.5 1 2 3 4
```

Which allows the values to be given meaningful formats:

```
>>> print '{:.2%} {}'.format(.5, ' '.join(map(str,a)))
50.00% 1 2 3 4
```